# Are setTimeout() and setInterval() functions async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, setinterval

I read that `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are used to imitate async behaviour. But I don't know if they really are.

Comment: Yes they are async

Comment: @AlonEitan just to add: but they don't return a promise.

Answer (score 3):

They are asynchronous and run in the JavaScript [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). However they are not `async`, which is a syntactic sugar around functions that work with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

We can provide a concrete example of how `setTimeout` is used to easily leverage `async` and `await`. Click **run snippet** to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))  // <- Promise around setTimeout
  
async function main()
{ console.log("powering on. please wait ...")
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log("initializing system resources...")
  await sleep(1500)
  console.log("133 MHZ CPU deteced")
  await sleep(1200)
  console.log("64 KB RAM available")
  await sleep(2000)
  console.log("120 MB hard drive deteced")
  await sleep(500)
  console.log("registering PCI devices...")
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log("starting MS-DOS...")
  return "ready"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
powering on. please wait ...
initializing system resources...
133 MHZ CPU deteced
64 KB RAM available
120 MB hard drive deteced
registering PCI devices...
starting MS-DOS...
ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Both take a function as a parameter and schedule that function to be executed later. So, one could say they are "async" in a sense. However, in JavaScript the "async" word has a very specific meaning, since `async` is a keyword used to declare a function, and in this sense they are not async, since they do not return a Promise.

Comment: 1. `async` is very new syntax for a very old concept. There have been asynchronous operations which were called "async" for short way before `async` was added to the language. 2. Since you want to be pedantic here and claim that `setTimeout` is not async because it doesn't use the `async` keyword, I'd like to point out that there is no `async` keyword. If there was [this wouldn't be possible](https://jsbin.com/lejilemiqi/edit?js,console)

Answer (score -1):

quick answer javascript is synchronous but some callbacks act async.

the setTimeout() function will be triggered in the stack, then continue on with what comes after even though it has not finished its timer.

Javascript is naturally synchronous, but some callbacks are async like setTimeout and setInterval, now if you want to wait for something, consider using a promise instead `new Promise(() => console.log()`. - I gave bad information, fixed it now

If you write a simple block of code like so, you'll notice that `non timeout` will print then `interval` then `timeout` even though it's laid in the opposite order.

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'), 3000)
setInterval(() => console.log('interval'), 2000)
console.log('non timeout')
```

Comment: `await setTimeout()` will not wait until completion because `setTimeout` does not return a promise. Only promises can be awaited.